# Google Sites button is always showing in the middle for phone and tablet preview

Tags: google-sites

Can we align the buttons in google sites to left/right? Because right now it will always align to middle in phone and tablet preview.

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je33r.png)

Even though I add it to the left corner it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To align the buttons in google sites to left/right, you can set the text align of the button to left or right.

[image: Google Sites button alignment]

Then you need to enlarge the size of the element:

[image]

It will align correctly on phone and tablet preview:

[image]